# material angular syntax error on dataTable

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Material2 for my frontend and i got this question, Why in my IDE "let row" is highlighted as an error but compiling the code there is no problem?

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: WebStorm from JetBrains

Comment: even my `my-eclipse` does that sometimes, to make sure there isnt a real error I cut and paste the same line. And if there is no error the red line just goes away.